# Widget SiriKit intent enum value for index

Tags: sirikit, widgetkit

I'm trying to add another `SiriKit` intent to my Widget to allow user to select a reddit category such as top, hot, new etc. I've set my enum in my custom intents. My question is how do I get the **display name** from the *index*? It's being assigned to a URL string so the `rawValue` won't work. I attempted to use `Sort(rawValue:configuration.sort.rawValue)!` with the same results `https://www.reddit.com/r/swiftui/1.json`. I need the url to be`https://www.reddit.com/r/swiftui/hot.json`.

[image: Intents]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating an Int `enum` containing the same as in my `intentdefinition`. Then created an `extension` for my `enum` to return a string value for the intent's `rawValue`. I was **mistaken** that my `intentdefinition` would provide me a string value for the index.

```swift
enum SortBy : Int {
    case hot = 1
    case new
    case controversial
    case top
    case rising
}

extension SortBy {
    var sortValue: String {
        switch self {
        case .hot:
            return "hot"
        case .new:
            return "new"
        case .controversial:
            return "controversial"
        case .top:
            return "top"
        case .rising:
            return "rising"
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
SortBy(rawValue: configuration.sort.rawValue)!
```